# How to Show blob of video...In localhost

Tags: javascript, angular5, recordrtc

I am using angular 4 and as I am recording from webcam using recordRTC... I am getting a blob... And I want to show that video in the view... And I don't know what is the way to show in the interface...Can anybody suggest me the w

```js
 processVideo(audioVideoWebMURL) {
    let video: HTMLVideoElement = this.video.nativeElement;
    let recordRTC = this.recordRTC;
    video.src = audioVideoWebMURL;
    console.log(video.src);
    //this console giving blob of 
    //[Eg:blob:http://localhost:4500/43113be2-c54e-42f6-b1bd-9b5907439e77]
    this.toggleControls();
    var recordedBlob = recordRTC.getBlob();
    recordRTC.getDataURL(function (dataURL) {
      console.log(dataURL);
      //this Console giving base64 string...
    });


  }
```